# Regex in Flex 3: How to Wrap Quotations Around a Dynamic String?

Tags: regex, apache-flex

I need some Regex help.

I need to find beacon_ followed by an alphanumeric code and then wrap it in quotation marks. For something static, like the example, below it's straight forward.

```
myReturn = myReturn.replace( 'id=beacon_80291ee9b3', 'id="beacon_80291ee9b3"');
```

But, my problem is that the part after beacon is a *random* alphanumeric code. (However, it is always the same length). For example, the beacon part could be:

- beacon_c8ac873136
- beacon_dc83b5953e
- beacon_7a910d03d8

etc.

The haystack that I'll search will look like:

```
myReturn = "blah blah id=beacon_80291ee9b3 blah blah";
```

Thanks.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a set like `[0-9a-z]` to match an alphanumeric character, and use `{10}` to specify how many. Use parentheses to specify what to match, and `$1` to use the match in the replacement:

```
myReturn = myReturn.replace('id=(beacon_[0-9a-z]{10})', 'id="$1"');
```

Comment: Hi Guffa,

Thank you! It worked perfectly. And I appreciated the explanation.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0):

```
myReturn = myReturn.replace('id=beacon_(\w{10})', 'id="beacon_$1"');
```

Comment: Hi Alan,
Thank you for the help. Much appreciated.

-Laxmidi